# Looking for an English word or personality associated with "quality", "humour", and "elegance"

Tags: vocabulary, personification

I am looking for an English word or famous personality or anyone famous who can be associated with *quality*, *funny* and *elegant*.

If I could find all three qualities in a single subject that would be excellent,
otherwise a combination of any two is also fine.

Comment: Oscar Wilde comes to mind as a famous personality.The quality of his writings characterised by a subtle sense a humour. He is also remembered  for his peculiar elegance.

Comment: Shaw, for sure: *Nearly all his writings address prevailing social problems with a vein of comedy which makes their stark themes more palatable.* Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_Bernard_Shaw *In his old age, Shaw was a household name in English-speaking countries, and was famed throughout the world. His ironic wit endowed English with the adjective "Shavian", used to characterize observations such as: "My way of joking is to tell the truth. It's the funniest joke in the world."*

Comment: Another "hit & run" questioner, I fear.

Comment: @Mari-LouA What are those?

Comment: @moonstar2001  It's a coined expression, I invented on the fly. It describes a user who posts a question and then disappears without trace. If you're interested in knowing more, I posted and updated a [feature request](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/5222/decluttering-the-new-questions-page-on-elu) on meta. I apologize for the self-promotion but I do feel quite strongly about this matter.

Comment: Wilde & Shaw are great suggestions, but they really include that kind of "gay" aspect, plus they're very sort of 1800s.

Comment: Bob Newhart. Don

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Dandy*** is a term that is coming back in fashion. It denotes a man who pays particularly attention to detail, in the way he dresses, speaks and holds himself. It is synonymous with style and good taste.

Like a peacock, a dandy will stand out in the crowd, he will both be admired and scorned for his regal elegant appearance. The most famous of dandies was a certain Mr. Oscar Wilde.

A book has been recently published written by Nathaniel Adams, entitled *[I am  Dandy The Return of the Elegant Gentleman](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/cator-sparks/i-am-dandy-no-im-not-a-ne_b_4073437.html)*

> How are dandies regarded in Paris?
>
> It is definitely a novelty in Paris. They see it more of a celebration
>   of the individual, not a negative connotation. **It means someone with
>   personality and flair.**
>   (...)
>   Also what I have seen is that walking down the street with dandies and seeing how people react to them is so interesting. (...) You can walk down the street in jeans or in a cape and people will certainly treat you differently.

Wikipedia defines a dandy as

> A **dandy** (also known as a beau or gallant) is a man who places
>   particular importance upon physical appearance, refined language, and
>   leisurely hobbies, pursued with the appearance of nonchalance in a
>   cult of Self

Another Englishman famed for his physical appearance, wit, humour and charm was **[Beau Brummell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dandy#Beau_Brummell_and_early_British_dandyism)** his full and proper name being George Bryan Brummell (1778–1840). King George IV referred to him as *the first gentleman of England*.

The same Wikipedia article describes the precursor of the modern day *[socialite](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/socialite)* as

> ... always perfectly brushed, perfectly fitted, showing much
>   perfectly starched linen, all freshly laundered, and composed with an
>   elaborately knotted cravat. From the mid-1790s, Beau Brummell was the
>   early incarnation of "the celebrity", a man chiefly famous for being
>   famous—in his case, as a laconically witty clothes-horse. (...) Moreover, he led the transition from *breeches* to snugly tailored dark "pantaloons," which directly led to contemporary trousers, the sartorial mainstay of men's clothes in the Western world for the past two centuries.

In 2002 a [statue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beau_Brummell#mediaviewer/File:Beau_Brummell_Statue_Jermyn_Street.JPG) in honour of Beau Brummell was erected in Jermyn Street, London.

Comment: nice 80s Beau Brummell reference .. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5eAQa4MOGkE

Comment: Mari-Luv, I'm not really sure that these do it for the "funny" aspect.

Comment: TBC "Dandy" is probably the perfect answer.

Comment: @JoeBlow the OP asked "a combination of any two is also fine." but Brummell's fame, if you read the Wikipedia articles dedicated to him, was due not only to his elegance but also his wit.

Comment: I never read wikipedia, because I'm quality humour and elegance.  But I've read a lot about B.B. and that era!  **You're quite right**, he was a wit.  It's astounding that he, essentially, invented what we think of as "men's clothing - suits" today.  It's also astounding and difficult to grasp the look of men's clothing pre-Brummel.

Comment: Time for champagne

Comment: In a nifty coincidence, just as I was reading this, Billy Joel's "It's Still Rock and Roll to Me" was playing on the office sound system.

Answer (score 0):

The only perfect answers I can think of are Winston Churchill ...

{Scores impossibly highly on all three counts.  Quality: from the leading aristocratic family, eg born in Blenheim, etc. Humour: invented whole branches of same ("purple prose" etc), world's most famous piquant speaker etc. Elegance: incurable dandy about his clothes, military uniforms, hair, etc, invented whole major men's GQ looks (cigars, "blitz suits" etc), was always in debt from spending too much on elegance (Indeed, his quote *"In the end, it's cheaper at the Ritz..."* [totally incorrect!] perhaps epitomises, as a quote, the three qualities you're after!) }

... and Penelope Keith.

{Who is the English comedienne or comedian who is the epitome of Quality and Elegance - I can't even think of second place. She was of course the lead in the two most-famous brit TV comedies in the "quality, elegance" category, she was the lead in the most watched TV show of the 70s, is by far the highest-paid voice-actress, endorser etc in the "quality, elegance" category; she is a Dame and has letters after her name, etc.  You could point to, say, three (!) or more comedy sketches she starred in as being the most famous sketches involving a character who's an Elegant & Quality type (such as the "stairs" sketch of Morecombe and Wise).}

So, **Winston Churchill** and **Penelope Keith**.

Also, certainly H.M. Elizabeth II.  (The humour aspect is rather subtle.)

Answer (score -2):

exquisite; i.e., Marilyn Monroe